# Quartz org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException Error at start up

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler

I need to acces the SchedulerFactoryBean (Using 1.8 quartz with spring) from a method called from the UI to pause the Scheduler and make a batch update to the database.

But i cant get the bean injection to work, gives me an error:

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'runProcessBranchFolders': FactoryBean which is currently in creation returned null from getObject

Here is the relevant code (I hope) from the applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="cleanHistoricFolder" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="catalogFacadeTarget"/>
    <property name="targetMethod" value="cleanHistoricFolder"/>
    <property name="concurrent" value="false"/>
</bean>

<bean id="simpleTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerBean">
    <!-- see the example of method invoking job above -->
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="runProcessBranchFolders"/>
    <!-- 10 seconds -->
    <property name="startDelay" value="10000"/>
    <!-- repeat every 10 seconds -->
    <property name="repeatInterval" value="180000"/>
</bean>


<bean id="cleanHistoricFolderTrigger"   class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="cleanHistoricFolder"/>
    <!-- 1 minute -->
    <property name="startDelay" value="60000"/>
    <!-- repeat 24 hours -->
    <property name="repeatInterval" value="86400000"/>
</bean>




<bean id="schedulerFactoryBeanTarget" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="triggers">
        <list>

            <ref bean="simpleTrigger"/>
             <ref bean="cleanHistoricFolderTrigger"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- ========================= BUSINESS OBJECT DEFINITIONS ======================== -->

<bean  id="catalogFacadeTarget" class="com.bamboo.catW3.business.impl.CatalogFacadeImpl">
    <property name="categoryDAO">
        <ref local="categoryDAOTarget"/>

   .
   .
   .
    <property name="schedulerFactoryBean" >
        <ref local="schedulerFactoryBeanTarget" />  
    </property>
</bean>
```

Thank you very much in advance!